# Why is $result always returning me false?

Tags: php

I have this `insert.php` file that inserts data to my database but every time I submit data `$result` always returns false. I don't know where the problem is, its always echoing `"something error"`.

```
##Insert.php

include_once("connection.php");

if (
    isset($_POST['txtCarModel']) && isset($_POST['txtCarType']) && 
    isset($_POST['txtCapacity']) && isset($_POST['image']) &&
    isset($_POST['txtFuelType']) && isset($_POST['txtPlateNumber']) && 
    isset($_POST['txtOwner'])
) {
    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $id = $now->format('YmdHis');

    $upload_folder = "upload";
    $path = "ftp://$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $fullpath = "carkila.esy.es/$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";

    $Car_Model = $_POST['txtCarModel'];
    $Car_Type = $_POST['txtCarType'];
    $Capacity = $_POST['txtCapacity'];
    $Fuel_Type = $_POST['txtFuelType'];
    $PlateNumber = $_POST['txtPlateNumber'];
    $Image = $_POST['image'];
    $Owner = $_POST['txtOwner'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_cars (Car_Model, owner, Car_Type,Capacity,fuelType,carPlatenuNumber,Image) VALUES ('$Car_Model', '$Owner', '$Car_Type',$Capacity,'$fuelType','$carPlatenuNumber','$Image')"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if ($result > 0) {
        if (isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android") {
            echo "success";
            exit;
    }
    echo "Insert Successfully";   
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android") {
        echo "failed";
        exit;
    }
    echo "Something Error";   
}
```

Comment: Take advantage of mysqli's prepared statements, and use `mysqli_error` to check for issues.

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` say? The result is `0` when there's an error, so you need to find out what error happened.

Comment: Note that `mysqli_query` returns `true` or `false` with an INSERT query, not a number.

Comment: What is the output of query when you just run the query in mysql editor?

Comment: @aynber - `$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_cars ("Car_Model, owner, Car_Type,Capacity,fuelType,carPlatenuNumber,Image") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';` will this do the trick? then `$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);` ??

Comment: Change `echo "failed";` to `echo "Error: " . mysqli_error();`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Oh yeah i forgot it returns me false. Hahaha. Ill edit it :D

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte:  Yes but still, `true > 0` and `false` NOT `> 0`.

Comment: @igop Yes, then you need to bind_param, then execute. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Remove the `>0` part from the if statement. Just `if($result)` should be sufficient

Comment: `<br /><b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in <b>/home/u850332371/public_html/insert.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />`

Comment: @AbraCadaver technically - if you want to get really nit-picky `true != 0` and `false == 0` (i.e. -1 would be true).

Comment: @igop sorry, try `echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);`

Comment: That's impressive that your code echos `something wrong` because I can only see `Something Error` in your script. Very impressive, I give it an 8 out of 7

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: yes, however the expression in the code is `($result > 0)`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  - Sorry sir for my incompetence and my lack of intelligence for your superiority I've fixed it already. Once again I'm sorry I'm just here to learn. Still thanks :)

Comment: You should try to put `var_dump($_POST['mobile']);` before your query to see what happens.

Comment: At no point did I say anything about superiority and I embrace learners but if you don't care enough to make your question factually accurate and reflect your code then why should others care? What if your mistake was more severe and you sent people on a wild goose chase? Anyways, go brush up on the [**Return Values**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues) section if you wish to program with competence going forward; this applies for everything you try to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_cars (Car_Model, owner, Car_Type,Capacity,fuelType,carPlatenuNumber,Image) VALUES ('$Car_Model', '$Owner', '$Car_Type',$Capacity,'$fuelType','$carPlatenuNumber','$Image')";
```

$carPlatenuNumber should be $plateNumber

Answer (score -1):

Use `mysqli_affected_rows ()`

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result = mysqli_affected_rows ($conn);
```

It will return the number of rows affected by the previous operation.

[mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)